# how to call the submit button click event after the blur event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have created one form there is three fields firstname, lastname,email. 3 diffrent buttons
add more,delete,submit.

if user click on add button then we have to add 4 more fields, firstname,lastname,email,delete button.

if click on delete button then remove that 4 fields.

and click on submit button then submit form.

now one validation is that if email text field lost focus then check weather the email is exist or not. then perform click of others.

every thing is going well but the click event of button is not working after the blur.

```
 /*To check weather email address is exist or not on lostfocus event of the email text box start here */
    $(".userEmail").live("focusout",function(){
        startLoading();
        value=$(this).val();
        element=$(this);
        $(this).live("focus");
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url:"isEmailExist.html",
            data:{email:value},
            success : function(data){
                endLoading();
                if(data.returnVal == "true")
                {
                    element.addClass("emailExistAlready")
                }   
                else
                {
                    element.removeClass("emailExistAlready");                       
                }
            },
            error:function(jqXHR)
            {
                errorAjax();
                endLoading();
                ajaxErrorCode(jqXHR);
            }
        });
    });
    /*To check weather email address is exist or not on lostfocus event of the email text box end here */

    /*To add more element on click of the link of add new User start here*/
    $("#addMoreUser").live("mousedown",function(){
        $("#addNewUser").append($(".addUserClone").html());
    });
    /*To add more element on click of the link of add new User end here*/

    /*To remove the elemnts on click of the remvoe botton start here */
    $(".deleteField").live("mousedown",function(){
        $(this).parent().parent("tr").remove();
    });
    /*To remove the elemnts on click of the remvoe botton end here */
```

i have used mousedown for the add and delete button but i cannot use mousedown for the submmit but then what can i do?

Comment: Wat's your code , give ur code sample .

Comment: share what you have written so far.

Comment: Do you want to call the submit button event in focusout event??then you can add below given line to your "focusout" method.
 $("#idOfSubmitButton").trigger("click");

Comment: i want to call submit button event if the user click on submit button.

if user's focus on email textbox and now click on submit button then i want to call first focus out event of the textbox and suddenly click event of the submit button